# In the Chrome Dev Tools Paint Profiler, what do the colours signify?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, paint

Chrome Dev Tools has a section for profiling the paint request of a layer.
This is accessed by opening Dev Tools, recording a timeline trace and then select the Paint Profiler tab (click Esc if it is not visible).

On the right there is a pie chart which breaks down the paint operations into  one of three colours:

- Blue
- Purple
- Orange

My question is, what do these colours signify?

See Also: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas?hl=en

[image]

Comment: Yes, lots of it. I've even linked to the most recent page. It shows the pie chart but does not state what each colour is. Note, I am talking about the pie chart, not the green/purple/yellow used elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors mean what type of drawing operations they are:

pink (shapes), blue (bitmap), green (text), purple (misc.).

refs: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/devtools-timeline-now-providing-the-full-story?hl=en#paint-profiler